# How to prepare while(@@rowcount>0)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I am using sql server.

I have a piece of code like this

```
while(@@rowcount>0)
begin
--do stuff
end
```

The thing is, I want to make something neat and tidy that makes sure the FIRST iteration will run. What do you propose to put before? Currently, I have used a

```
select 'Calling this to initialize @@rowcount to 1'
```

which is self-explanatory, but if there's something better, I'd like to know.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, there's probably a better way to organise your query.

Comment: The best approach here would be to use a set based instead of looping at all.

Comment: I am using some headache-invoking patindex stuff in order to replace every nonnnumeric sequence of an nvarchar into a specific symbol. I do it one pattern per iteration, I doubt there is a set-based way to do this that is not insanely complicated. I'd make a post, but I'm sick of negative reputation ;)

Comment: I guess if you are ok with the performance then so be it. I have no idea what your replace logic is so can't really help there. I suspect it could be done set based but can't really tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a variable allows you to handle the initial condition separately and preserves the value of `@@RowCount` if *doing stuff* may have several steps:

```
declare @RowCount as Int = 42;
-- Initialize   @RowCount   to skip the loop entirely, if appropriate.

while @RowCount > 0
  begin
  -- Do stuff;
  set @RowCount = @@RowCount;
  -- Perhaps do more stuff that might affect   @@RowCount .
  end;
```

Alternatively, a variable can be used to handle only the first pass through the loop:

```
declare @FirstPass as Bit = 1;
-- Initialize   @FirstPass to skip the loop entirely, if appropriate.
-- Note that the loop will always be entered once if   @@RowCount   has not been cleared.

while @@RowCount > 0 or @FirstPass = 1
  begin
  set @FirstPass = 0;
  -- Do stuff;
  end;
```

My preference is to use the first method as it is clear, simple and provides a captured value of `@@RowCount` that can be used for logging, debugging, ... without being concerned about which statements might alter the value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the old GOTO

```
startloop:
  -- do stuff
IF @@rowcount > 0 GOTO startloop
```

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter than the accepted answer

```
select 1
while(@@rowcount>0)
begin
--do stuff
end
```

Comment: this was the solution QA was using when asking the question

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Are you sure this is the exact solution used by OP?  I bet they did not know that they could use a static select.

Comment: quite sure: select 'Calling this to initialize @@rowcount to 1'

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Then why would they not just post static select?

Comment: it is a static select